# How to replace a particular String with another String in the currently opened editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hi, I m doing a eclipse plugin project to create an IDE. In my IDE,the
 currently opened editor is checked for a particular string and should
 be replaced by a string entered in the textbox which is in the side
 view. I m able to access the editor but if i search for the particular
 string and replace that string with the input entered by the user it
 is not working.

```
 IDocumentProvider provider=((AbstractTextEditor) ieditorpart).getDocumentProvid();
 IDocument doc = provider.getDocument(ieditorpart.getEditorInput());  
 String content = doc.get();
 pos=content.compareTo("\\/\\*ProbeEnd\\*\\/");
 doc.replace(pos,5, "hello");
```

But this is not working... here i have just given the replacement
 string as hello,but that value should be taken from the textbox..

Is there any mistake in accessing the editor? should i use this
 approach to do this or is there any approach to implement this? Can
 Anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the variable 'pos' the compareTo-Value (-1,0,1)? The compareTo returns the lexicographical order of the two Strings.

The replace method of [IDocument](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/IDocument.html) has three parameters:

- int offset - the offset in the document, where 'text' should be inserted
- int length - the length starting from 'offset', which should be overwritten. length 0 means insert.
- String text - the substitution text

Example:

```
String oldContent = doc.get();
assert oldContent.equals("TestingText");

String replaceText = "REPLACE";

doc.replace(5,3,replaceText);

String newContent = doc.get();
assert newContent.equals("TestiREPLACEext");
//offset 5 is the position after 'Testi'
//length 3 means 'ngT' (starting from the offset) should be replaced
//REPLACE is the newText
```

Answer (score 0):

Call firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_INPUT) from your editor.

Comment: in default texteditors, the editor registered an listener to the document and is informed about a replace directly. It is not necessary to fire that the input changed.